# Adding space between rows of tabular and array environments

Tags: spacing

How can I add space between the rows of a `tabular` or an `array` environment so that it looks like I used an `alignat` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&a \quad && b \\
&c \quad && d\\
&e \quad && f
\end{alignat*}

\[
\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    a & b  \\
    c & d  \\
    e & f
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't mind switching to the `tabu` packe maybe the use of `\tabulinesep` as explained in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64338/134144) answer might be usefull as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that changing the row spacing won't affect the math style. In `array` environments, the default math style is `\textstyle`, whereas in the multi-line equation environments of the `amsmath` package, the default math style is `\displaystyle`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting so that it makes use of an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, given that the contents of the environment appear to be math-related. Feel free to revert if you feel the modification is inappropriate or fails to address something important.

Answer (score 1):

`\extrarowheight=3pt` roughly does the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&a\quad && b \\
&c \quad && d\\
&e \quad&& f
\end{alignat*}

\[ \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    e & f
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From your mwe it is not exactly clear to me where to use `extrarowsep`.

Comment: The downsides of this approach are (a) it doesn't scale easily if the document font size is changed from, e.g., `10pt` to `12pt`, and (b) it inserts vertical whitespace above all rows, including the very first row -- which may not be desirable.

Comment: @leandriis: Sorry. I didn't see I had a clipboard breakdown: I copied your initial code, instead of the code in my editot. I've fixed it, and took the opportunity to replace `tabular` with `array`, as suggested by Mico.

Comment: @Mico: Sure it's not universal, but I don't like very much ` \arraystretch`, as it induces asymmetric modifications between height and depth of the row.

Comment: Not “roughly”, actually: the default value of `\jot` is 3pt

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the information. Actually I didn't even try to find the exact value, not knowing where to look for. I simply measured with my viewer.

Comment: The vertical size of the `array` will be `\jot` bigger than `alignedat`, because the two use different models.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the value of `\arraystretch` to `1.25`. (The default value is `1.00`.)

A full MWE, which provides a custom `array`-like environment called `myarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{myarray}[2][c]{%
   \begingroup
   \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
   \begin{array}[#1]{#2}}{%
   \end{array}
   \endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&a\quad && b \\
&c \quad && d\\
&e \quad&& f
\end{alignat*}

\[
\begin{myarray}{@{}ll@{}}
    a   & b  \\
    c   & d  \\
    e   & f
\end{myarray}
\]
\end{document}
```